# Insert elements in a contenteditable div after the last inserted element

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, text-editor

I am actually working on a wysiwyg editor and I want to insert dynamically a note bar and an alert bar (both are DIVs where you can type your text ) like this [Note](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wjWi.png) after the last inserted element, but it's not working and if I click another time on the insertion button it doesn't insert anything. besides, I want the alerte div to be placed before note div if I insert it first. Can anyone help me, do you have a better solution to add a delemited editable textarea in my editor  ?

```js
$(function () {
        $("#add").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $new = $('#bar');
            $('#bar').append('<div id="bar">');
            $new.show('slow');
        });
        
       
        $("#add2").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var $new = $('#alerte');
            $('#alerte').append('<div id="alerte">');
            $new.show('slow');
        });
    });
```

```html
    <!-- editer le contenu.-->
    <div class="editor" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">
        Text Editor ...
        <div id="bar" style="display: none"; >
     <div class="Note" contenteditable="false" spellcheck="true"> <b>Note</b></div>
        <div class="NoteContenu" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">
  </div> 
    </div> 
    <div  id="alerte" style="display: none";>
     <div class="Attention" contenteditable="false" spellcheck="true"> <b>Attention</b></div>
        <div class="AlerteContenu" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">
  </div> 
    </div> 
    </div>
<button id="add" >Note </button>
<button id="add2" >Alerte </button>
```